# How to play song in pygame music for a set period of time or until a button is pushed?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using pygame music to play an mp3 for a specific amount of time.  However, how do I use a button to stop/fadeout of the song before the time is up?  I've tried sleep, and sleep on a short loop, but its not detecting the button push.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just call [`pygame.mixer.music.stop`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) when the button is pushed.

```py
if button_pushed:
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

If you mat to fade out the music call [`pygame.mixer.music.fadeout()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.fadeout). The argument is the time in milliseconds

```py
if button_pushed:
    pygame.mixer.music.fadeout(5000) # 5 seconds
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wrote that poorly.  I'm playing a song and having it fadeout before it is over.  To set how long before the fadeout/stop, I am using sleep. However, I also want to be able to stop the music with a button push before the time is up, and the sleep function is blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from time import sleep
```

then

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(0, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


#code before 10 sec count
Pygame.mixer.music.play()
interrupt = false
millisecondPassed = 0
while true:
    input_state = GPIO.input(18)
    if input_state == False:
        interrupt = true
    sleep(0.01) #wait for 1 millisecond
    millisecondPassed += 1
                
    if millisecondPassed >= 10000 or interrupt == true:
        break
#code after interruption
```

Finally

```
pygame.mixer.music.fadeout(5000)
```

or

```
pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

As for reference: 10 seconds = 10000 milliseconds

Comment: How would I do that with a gpio button press?

Comment: as in General-purpose input/output?

Comment: what do you mean by gpio press?

Comment: And are you using Rasberry Pi or something?

Comment: It does!  Problem is i need it for a gpio button press.  I'm using gpio zero, and trying to replace KEYBOARD in your code with the custom event .STOP_Button.  I've defined it as a USEREVENT before the while statement, but it won't accept it as an event type.  Also, it doesn't seem to time out after the 10 seconds in this example.

Comment: ok i edited my code but I've never tried it before cause I don't have a raspberry pi

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to make a soundboard for Little League walkup music (with a Stop button in case music is played at the wrong time).  My son and i are trying to make it with a headless raspberry pi that takes all input from gpio buttons.  Its fun, but in a little over our heads.